# Unable to integrate Google Sign In using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using Firebase to integrate Google Sign In on my Android application. 
Here's my code:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .requestIdToken("685357920901-sfghh9b8heq89b3g1l7gun3csuilur5c.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();



    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, null)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("here", "not");
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d("here", "ohyeah");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}


public void SignIn(View view) {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        Log.d("here", "o   "+result);
        Log.d("here", "o00000       "+result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            Log.d("here", "success");
        } else {
            Log.d("here", "fail");

        }
    }
}
```

My result from:

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
```

is of the form :

```
"com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@3fbdc9ad".
```

Still, the `isSuccess()` method is returning false. Please help, I am stuck. I have added all the dependencies, as well as have got the Google JSON file. The request token is also correct, still I'm unable to detect the root of the problem.

Comment: is there any success?

Comment: Yeah, I got that. There were lot of things involved like auth key, which can be achieved from google api console, and then SHA-1 .. etc. I got it finally.